# Using Recursion On an ArrayList

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

Okay so, I am given an `ArrayList<Integer> num` with **[1,2,3,4]** already in it. My job is to sum the squares and then place the square of each int into the `ArrayList` next to the number **[1,1,2,4,3,9,4,16]**

I figured out the sum of squares part. I am not sure how to proceed with adding the squared numbers into the area.

Should I make a new `ArrayList` and figure it out from there? Maybe a helper method?

Also, I’m not allowed to use any loops.

Comment: Yes, it would be better to create new arraylist and update it during calculating the square of each number.

Answer (score 0):

You can check start with index 0 and recursively call the method to update the **Output List** till the size of **Input List**. You can do it like below using **recursion**.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
    final List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    final int index = 0;

    if (index < input.size()) {
      updateList(input, output, index);
    }

    System.out.println(output);

  }

  private static void updateList(final List<Integer> input, final List<Integer> output, int index) {

    output.add(input.get(index));
    output.add(input.get(index) * input.get(index));

    ++index;

    if (index < input.size()) {
      updateList(input, output, index);
    }

  }
```

**Input :** [1, 2 3, 4,]
**Output :** [1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16]